# Mysql: How to iterate Table A to Generate N-Number rows based on row count?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, do-while

I have created a stored procedure.  I want to generate N number of rows based on column from table A.

Eg:

```
select date 
from calendar 
where date between DATE1 and DATE2;
```

For example, here I will get 10 days. So I want to generate rows for 10 days. How to achieve this using a stored procedure? Or is their any better suggestion?

I have tried:

```
set @total_days_count = 0;
set @row_iterate = 0;
set @curr_date = NULL;

select @total_days_count:=count(*) 
from calendar 
where date between from_date and to_date;

while (@row_iterate < @total_days_count) do
    set @total_days_count = @total_days_count + 1;
    select 
        *
    from Table2 WHERE date = @curr_date;
end while;
```

is their any better suggestions?

Comment: You can use cursor, which works like charm!

Comment: thanks @James will try cursor